# What tasks can be done inside a firebase message service when app is not open?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

> I am trying to read Shared Preferences file in the OnMessageRecevied method of firebase Messaging service.

**Unfortunately , i am not able to find a way to do this because when the app service is running in background I don't have a context object. :(**

Any workaround of fix for this ?

So i guess when it comes to performing certain tasks in the background , there are some limitations on what we could do ...

So I want to know the scope of tasks or operations (stuff) we can perform after receiving the firebase message.

Comment: `FirebaseMessagingService` is derived from [Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service), which is derived from `Context`.  You can call `getSharedPreferences()` from `onMessageReceived()`.

Comment: oh my got I just realized that later . Thank you . I would mark that an answer if u write one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FirebaseMessagingService` is derived from [Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service), which is derived from `Context`. You can call `getSharedPreferences()` in `onMessageReceived()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code inside **FirebaseMesaagingService**

```
SharedPreferences sp = this.getSharedPreferences("SP", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("download", true);
                    editor.apply();
```